# Polymer conflict with moment.js?

Tags: polymer, momentjs

I'm using moment.js in a Polymer filter, and all is wonderful in Chrome. And, then, there's Firefox. This code:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="time-ago" attributes="isostring prepend">
    <template>
        <span id="timeago">{{prepend}} {{ isostring | timeago }}</span>
    </template>

    <script src="/bower_components/time-ago/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        Polymer('time-ago', {
            ready: function() {

            },
            timeago: function(){
                return moment(arguments[0], moment.ISO_8601).fromNow();
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Creates this response:

```
"Exception caught during observer callback: .timeago@data:text/javascript;base64,CgkJUG9seW1lcigndGltZS1hZ28nLCB7CgkJCXJlYWR5OiBmdW5jdGlvbigpIHsKCQkJCQoJCQl9LAoJCQl0aW1lYWdvOiBmdW5jdGlvbigpewoJCQkJcmV0dXJuIG1vbWVudChhcmd1bWVudHNbMF0sIG1vbWVudC5JU09fODYwMSkuZnJvbU5vdygpOwoJCQl9CgkJfSk7CgkKLy8jIHNvdXJjZVVSTD1odHRwOi8vc3Vuc3BvdC5sb2NhbC9ib3dlcl9jb21wb25lbnRzL3RpbWUtYWdvL2luZGV4Lmh0bWwvdGltZS1hZ28uanMK:7:5
g.prototype.transform@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/polymer/polymer.js:12:1699
l.prototype.getValue@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/polymer/polymer.js:12:4483
l.prototype.getBinding@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/polymer/polymer.js:12:4279
b/<@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/polymer/polymer.js:11:30452
v@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:16:15082
w@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:16:15304
A@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:16:16251
A@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:16:16142
.createInstance@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:16:20171
c.instanceTemplate@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/polymer/polymer.js:12:14121
d.shadowFromTemplate@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/polymer/polymer.js:12:17324
d.parseDeclaration@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/polymer/polymer.js:12:17137
d.parseDeclarations@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/polymer/polymer.js:12:17028
d.makeElementReady@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/polymer/polymer.js:12:16292
d.createdCallback@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/polymer/polymer.js:12:15805
k@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:16:1615
h@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:16:1213
s@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:16:2616
h@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:15:28868
e@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:15:28571
g@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:15:28671
CustomElements[a]@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:16:5579
Document.prototype.importNode@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:16:26689
A@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:16:16069
A@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:16:16142
.createInstance@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:16:20171
E.prototype.handleSplices@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:16:24923
E.prototype.valueChanged@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:16:23131
E.prototype.updateIteratedValue@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:16:22883
ObserverTransform.prototype.observedCallback_@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:12:18460
Observer.prototype.report_@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:12:12599
CompoundObserver.prototype<.check_@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:12:18135
global.Platform.performMicrotaskCheckpoint@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:12:13514
b/<@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:16:26113
c@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:15:10963
c@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:12:26120
b@http://sunspot.local/bower_components/platform/platform.js:12:25652
"
```

Are there any known conflicts between moment.js and Polymer? Again, on Chrome its flawless. Only Firefox 31.0 is causing the problem.

UPDATE New code:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/time_ago/momentjs.html">
<polymer-element name="time-ago" attributes="isostring prepend">
    <template>
        <span id="timeago">{{prepend}} {{ isostring | timeago }}</span>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer('time-ago', {
            ready: function() {

            },
            timeago: function(){
                return moment(arguments[0], moment.ISO_8601).fromNow();
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: just to be sure, did you include the polymer platform script in your site?

Comment: Always a good catch! Yes, it's there.

Comment: Just continuing to work this out. The problem appears to be with the duration method within moment.js. I can successfully create the object, but any of the methods that draft off of the duration property trigger the same failure.

Comment: Can you reproduce the momentjs problem in Firefox without Polymer?

Comment: Thanks, Peter. moment.js runs smashingly by itself (even validated all of the test cases at http://momentjs.com/tests/ without flaws). And Polymer's running just fine. It's when the two meet that things fail.

Comment: [This jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tamicevu/1/edit?html,output) worked fine for me in Firefox 31.0. Is there something missing from it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't embed your script tag for `moment.js` inside your `<polymer-element>`. Put it outside of the `polymer-element` entirely. So, like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<script src="/bower_components/time-ago/moment.min.js"></script>
<polymer-element name="time-ago" attributes="isostring prepend">
```

Even better, if you have other elements that need to use `moment`, make an import for it (and html file that contains a script tag that loads `moment.min.js`) and use `<link>` to load the import everywhere you need it. This pattern allows multiple objects to access the `moment` api without duplicate loads.

Comment: Still no luck with that, trying both the <script src...> pattern and the include pattern. Am editing the original to reflect the new code. If I comment out the return of the timeago :function()..., I get the render I'd typically expect...but with the return of that function in place I get a complete fail of the render.

Comment: As an aside, if I try just outputting moment(arguments[0], moment.ISO8601) to console, I get a valid object. It's running the fromNow() method on that object that causes the failure to be thrown.

Comment: And, even more interesting - this page fails on Firefox as well: http://component.kitchen/components/cw-moment (not my code...). So the conflict appears to be with moment.js in this context.

Comment: I take that back! Sorry for the false alarm; after updating libraries and making sure all of the references were connected the code now works in Firefox. Thanks for your help!